# missing expression sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
  create_date
  ,resolved_date
  ,item
  ,site
  ,status
  ,contact_time
  ,impact_label
FROM
  mytable  
WHERE
  create_date BETWEEN to_date('2013/03/01','YYYY/MM/DD') 
   AND to_date('2015/08/06','YYYY/MM/DD')
and CASE item 
  WHEN in ('A','B') then '1'
  WHEN in ('C') then '2'
  WHEN in ('D') then '3'
  ELSE null 
  END 
GROUP BY
create_date
,resolved_date
,item
,site
,status
,contact_time
,impact_label
```

It says I have problem at the first when in, could someone please help?

Comment: Also, there might be a problem with group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `IN` inside `CASE` you need different syntax :

```
...
case 
   when item  in ('A','B') then '1' 
   when item in  ('C') then '2' 
   when item  in ('D') then '3' 
   --else null   -- no need , ELSE NULL is default behaviour of CASE
end ...
```

Or change `CASE` to correct simple search syntax:

```
 CASE item 
  WHEN 'A' THEN '1'
  WHEN 'B' THEN '1'
  WHEN 'C' THEN '2'
  WHEN 'D' THEN '3'
  ELSE NULL 
 END
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my query to your and it works but now it has a problem of "invalid relational operator" at group by?

Comment: @lydieuvu : Since it's part of `WHERE` you need to compare result of case with something , e.g. `WHERE create_date between ....   AND CASE ... END = '1' ` or whatever condition makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a value.  In your case, it is returning a string value.

The `WHERE` clause consists of *boolean* expressions.  A string is not a boolean expression.  I'm not sure what you intend, perhaps:

```
(CASE WHEN item in ('A','B') then '1'
      WHEN item in ('C') then '2'
      WHEN item in ('D') then '3'
      ELSE null 
 END) IS NOT NULL
```

(Note the changes both to the `CASE` and the addition of `IS NOT NULL`.)

However, that is a silly expression, because it is equivalent to:

```
item in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

Perhaps you want to add the `CASE` to the `SELECT`, giving it a proper column alias.